# Left join two tables on LHS rows that meet a condition, leave others as NA

Tags: r

Consider the following scenario:

```r
test <- data.frame(Id1  = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11), 
                   Id2  = c(3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 15, 9), 
                   Type = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1) )
test
#>   Id1 Id2 Type
#> 1   1   3    1
#> 2   2   4    1
#> 3   3  10    1
#> 4   4  11    2
#> 5   5  12    2
#> 6  10  15    2
#> 7  11   9    1
```

I want to join `test` on itself by `Id2 = Id1` only when `Type` has a certain value, e.g. `Type == 1` in such a way that I get the following result:

```r
#>   Id1 Id2 Type.x Id2.y Type.y
#> 1   1   3    1      10      1   # matches row 3
#> 2   2   4    1      11      2   # matches row 4
#> 3   3  10    1      15      2   # matches row 6
#> 4   4  11    2      NA     NA   # matches row 7 but Type != 1
#> 5   5  12    2      NA     NA   # Type !=1
#> 6   10 15    2      NA     NA   # Type !=1
#> 7   11  9    1      NA     NA   # Type == 1 but no matches
```

Since in this case, `test` represents a hierarchy, a join of this type would allow me to "expand" the hierarchy so that each row eventually terminated in an `Id2` that was not equal to any value of `Id1`.

How can one achieve such a join?

Comment: What happened to `10` in `Id2` matching the last row of `Id1`?

Comment: @thelatemail Good catch. I corrected the example. The gist is that the 6th term wouldn't be matched on the join because Type == 2, not 1

Comment: Re it being a hierarchy, maybe try the igraph package. (Your desired output still doesn't make sense to me, so I can't answer -- you show 2 4 1 getting matched to a row with type 2 but 3 10 1 is not matched)

Comment: @Frank Bleh, I keep messing up my example. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse is a great package for data manipulation. Here, we can do as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
joined <- test %>% left_join(test %>% filter(Type==1), by = c("Id1" = "Id2"))
joined
```

UPDATE:

```
library(tidyverse)
joined <- test %>%
  filter(Type==1) %>% left_join(test, by = c("Id2" = "Id1")) %>%
  bind_rows(test %>% filter(Type==2) %>% rename(Type.x = Type))
joined


Id1 Id2 Type.x Id2.y Type.y
1   3   1   10  1
2   4   1   11  2
3   10  1   15  2
11  9   1   NA  NA
4   11  2   NA  NA
5   12  2   NA  NA
10  15  2   NA  NA
```

Comment: Thanks, but that solution does not work as desired. The 4th element gets joined even when it's Type == 2.